# Using ActiveRecord relationships to contain multiple instances of an object per row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationships

I am trying to figure out how to use ActiveRecord relationships to relate a model that can contain multiple instances of another model within one row.  For example, having has_many :dogs in one model, and belongs_to :dog in the other means that in the one model, "dog_id" will refer to an instance of :dog.  However, I want to be able to have multiple instances of :dog within my related (has_many) model, such as dog_id1, dog_id2, dog_id3, etc.  See the code below to understand what I mean.  How can I do this?

I have the following models:

```
--tp.rb
class Tp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :cats
  has_many :stars
  attr_accessible :dog_id1, :dog_id2, :dog_id3, :dog_id4, :cat_id1, :cat_id2, :cat_id3, :cat_id4, :star_id, :tp_id
end

--dog.rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord::
  belongs_to :tp
  attr_accessible :dog_id, :dog_name
end

--cat.rb
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tp
  attr_accessible :cat_id, :cat_name
end

--star.rb
 class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :tp
   attr_accessible :patient_id
 end
```

Comment: Did you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your `belongs_to`/`has_many` a little backwards.

## belongs_to and has_many

For your example,

```
class Tp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :cats
  has_many :stars
end
```

`Tp` doesn't have any `dog_id`, `cat_id`, or `star_id` in its database row. When you set `belongs_to` in the other models,

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tp
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tp
end

class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tp
end
```

You should add a `tp_id` to each model (`dogs` table, `cats` table, and `stars` table).

Then, calling

```
tp = Tp.find(123)
```

Finds `Tp` with `id` equal to 123

```
SELECT * FROM tps WHERE id = 123;
```

And calling

```
cats = tp.cats
dogs = tp.dogs
stars = tp.stars
```

Finds all `Cat`, `Dog`, and `Star` instances with `tp_id` equal to 123

```
SELECT * FROM cats WHERE tp_id = 123;
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE tp_id = 123;
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE tp_id = 123;
```

If you need your `Cat` instances to belong to many `Tp` instances, and `Tp` instances to have many `Cat` instances, then you should look at Rails's [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) or [has_many :through](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

## has_and_belongs_to_many

A `has_and_belongs_to` relationship would require new tables `cats_tps`, `dogs_tps`, and `stars_tps`. These tables would have a schema of

```
cats_tps
  cat_id
  tp_id
dogs_tps
  dog_id
  tp_id
stars_tps
  star_id
  tp_id
```

Then in your models

```
class Tp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dogs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cats
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stars
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tps
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tps
end

class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tps
end
```

Now, running

```
tp = Tp.find(123)
cats = tp.cats
```

Generates the SQL

```
SELECT "cats".* FROM "cats" INNER JOIN "cats_tps" ON "cats"."id" = "cats_tps"."cat_id" WHERE "cats_tps"."tp_id" = 123;
```

Which is essentialy the query (get me a list of all the cat_ids that belong to Tp 123) and then (get me all the cats that match these cat ids).

Generating the `cats_tps` join table can be done with a migration like

```
class CreateCatsTps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cats_tps, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :cat
      t.belongs_to :tp
    end
  end
end
```

This works great for simple joins, but you may want to look into using `has_many :through`. This is because the `cats_tps` table holds no information about when or why this `Cat` belongs to a `Tp` or this `Tp` belongs to the `Cat`. Likewise, if you add `Bird`, `Horse`, `Frog`, and `Snake` models, you will have to create `birds_tps`, `horses_tps`, `frogs_tps`, and `snakes_tps` tables. Yuck.

## has_many :through

To create a `has_many :through` relationship, you create a new model that makes sense semantically that links a `Tp` to a `Cat`. For instance, let's say that a `Tp` walks cats. You could create an `Walk` model that links a `Cat` to a `Tp`.

```
class Walk < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cat
  belongs_to :tp
  attr_accessible :price, :duration, :interval # these attributes describe the Walk relationship
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :walks
  has_many :tps, :through => :walks
end

class Tp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :walks
  has_many :cats, :through => :walks
end
```

Now, the relationship is similar to a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but you can include metadata about the walking relationship. Additionally, say that a `Tp` also walks dogs. You could convert the `belongs_to :cat` into a polymorphic `belongs_to :animal` relationship so that a `Tp` can walk a cat, dog, mouse, rabbit, horse, ... you name it.

```
class Walk < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tp
  attr_accessible :price, :duration, :interval # these attributes describe the Walk relationship
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :walks, :as => :animal
  has_many :tps, :through => :walks
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :walks, :as => :animal
  has_many :tps, :through => :walks
end

class Tp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :walks
  has_many :cats, :through => :walks, :source => :animal, :source_type => 'Cat'
  has_many :dogs, :through => :walks, :source => :animal, :source_type => 'Dog'
end
```

This relationship is created with a migration like

```
class CreateWalks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :walks do |t|
      t.belongs_to :animal, :polymorphic => true
      t.belongs_to :tp
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so if a Tp can be associated with many Cat and Dog entries, and a Cat and Dog can be associated with multiple Tp entries, I should be using one of the ActiveRecord many to many relationships that you have described in your post?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've updated the answer with information about the many-to-many relationships.

Comment: If I want to refer to say, just the cat_id column of the Cat object, how would I do so? using tp.cats.cat_id does not work, nor does tp.cats.id.

Comment: `tp.cats` is an array, so you can get the first cat id by running `tp.cats.first.id`, or you can get an array of all the cat ids with `tp.cats.map(&:id)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
attr_accessible :dog_id1, :dog_id2, :dog_id3, :dog_id4, :cat_id1, :cat_id2, :cat_id3, :cat_id4, :star_id, :tp_id
```

Your Dog model has a `tp_id` and the `has_many` and `belongs_to` allow you to do `tp_instance.dogs` to get an array of Dog models that have a matching `tp_id`

Answer (score 0):

remove the `:dog_id(s)` from the TP model and put `:tp_id` in your dog model. This will allow you to have a one-to-many relationship from TP to Dog